# iterating nested dictionaries using for loop in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

here is my json file which has sample data in nested dictionaries like below

```
data = {
    'school': {
        'name': 'abc',
        'class': {
            'firstclass': {'teacher': 'b', 'students': '10'},
            'secondclass': {'teacher': 'c', 'students': '25'},
        }, 'city': 'x'},
    'college': {
        'name': 'def',
        'class': {
            'firstclass': {'teacher': 'd', 'students': '9'},
            'secondclass': {'teacher': 'e', 'students': '65'},
        }, 'city': 'y'},
    'university': {
        'name': 'ghi',
        'class': {
            'firstclass': {'teacher': 'f', 'students': '55'},
            'secondclass': {'teacher': 'g', 'students': '22'},
        }, 'city': 'z'}
}
```

my output should be like:

```
'teacher':'b','students':'10'
'teacher':'d','students':'9'
'teacher':'f','students':'55'
```

here is my code in for loop:

```
for id in data:
    for j in data[id]:
        print(j  ,"="  , data[id][j])
```

i am not getting above expected output.
how to get exact output as above .

Comment: You are explicitly printing an `"="`, which is not even in your expected output?!

Comment: Also, pls post data structures that can be copied verbatim. That `data` of yours is **not** a valid `dict`

Comment: `for j in data[id]['class']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might nudge you in the right direction:

```
for v in data.values():
    for dct in v["class"].values():
        print(", ".join(map("=".join, dct.items())))
    
teacher=b, students=10
teacher=c, students=25
teacher=d, students=9
teacher=e, students=65
teacher=f, students=55
teacher=g, students=22
```

Comment: if i want to get only first class or second class from every class

Comment: Which first? Your desired output has 6 key-value pairs as has the output in this answer?

Comment: yes i got output exactly, but what if i want to get to only 
 dictionary of firstclass or second class  from class of school,college and university  .like firstclass from school,firstclass from college and firstclass from university data values

Comment: Then you would have to access those key combinations explicitly.

Comment: how to add time and date column to output.output should display like teachers,students,time,date .if possible pls share snippet

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad are you trying to read Stock/Index json? and wanna add time and date for the same? I can help.

Comment: Yes stock json data, now I am getting output of @user23901 but I need to include name value to the output from school,college, university also, will u help me

Comment: @John check above

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad I have a solution for reading Stocks and Index JSON which fetches data from NSE. If interested, pls let me know.

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad I too had a problem reading the data. Yesterday got solved. Here's the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545470/parsing-json-conditionally-using-python I hope this will help you if you wanna read the data as I am reading.

Comment: @john the above link doesn't help me, I need to read whole data

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad I am also reading the whole data, using this piece of code. Share you e-mail, if you can

Comment: @John palakoori05@gmail.com ,pls do help

Comment: @John, pls share