# parsing json conditionally using python

Tags: python, json

```
{
  "info": [
    {
      "subinfo": {
        "name": "ABC",
        "age": 23,
        "sex": "M",
        "addr": "xyz",
        "regDt": "01-Jan-2021"
      },
      "city": "NY",
      "eduInfo": {
        "deg": "BA",
        "master": "PhD"
      },
      "sports": {
        "indoor": "poker",
        "outdoor": "hockey"
      }
    },
    {
      "subinfo": {
        "name": "PQR",
        "age": 23,
        "sex": "F",
        "addr": "def",
        "regDt": "01-Jan-2021"
      },
      "city": "NY",
      "eduInfo": {
        "deg": "BA",
        "master": "NA"
      },
      "sports": {
        "indoor": "poker",
        "outdoor": "hockey"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above data is a simple example of what kind of data I am working with. There are
such **hundreds** of `info's` basically of Males and Females. I need two separate lists for both, Males and Females. So, to extract the data of Males i.e; `sex="M"`, I am using this condition

```
data = json.loads(data)

for m in data['info'] :
    if m['subinfo']['sex'] == "M" :
            mList = m

print(mList)

#and for Females list

for f in data['info'] :
    if f['subinfo']['sex'] == "F" :
            fList = f

print(fList)
```

I am expecting more than 1 record for each, Males and Females, but the actual result is
only one for each. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: your json is plainly wrong. It misses commas, proper formatting and there is a double key `info` which results to a single entry on load.

Comment: setting aside that you cannot have duplicate key "info" in json, is the value of it a list (array) or dict (object)? Currently there's a `[` opened but never closed

Comment: @re-za Actually, duplicate keys are valid in JSON. See [Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object)

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic There's a single `info`. Please check.

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic Before posting, I have checked the json format online. Here - https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @John Ouroborus edited the original json to comply with his answer (lol). The website you posted gives `6 Errors` in the original...

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic Yes. Ouroborus pointed this out. The original one which I edited, a few information, had errors and validated it. It seems I posted the wrong one. My fault. A serious crime. Apologies. But there's only one `info`. For sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the variable to the object each time. Because of this, the variable will be whatever the last matching object was. Instead, set the variable to an empty list and then append the objects to that list.

```py
mList = []
for m in data['info']:
    if m['subinfo']['sex'] == 'M':
         mList.append(m)
```

Comment: Well, the empty lists were declared in code, which I didn't share. Yes. `append()` was the must. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: the answer is wrong. Since the key `info` is a single entry, there aren't multiple records to append on. Thus, there are either multiple unique keys `info1`, `info2`, `info3` and you should remove the `info` from that bracket or there's no answer at all.

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic Asker seems to disagree with you. I suspect the JSON they provided is not representative of their actual data.

Comment: @Ouroborus the json they provided is not valid anyways (e.g. duplicate keys). And how did you decide that "info" is a list (array) not a dict (object) ? it's not clear in the question. If you have the privilege to do so, consider editing the question.

Comment: @re-za The JSON is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @Ouroborus I suspect the OP just stripped out the top level keys leaving only `info` and that's why your answer works for him. Since you have already given an accepted answer, I suggest to point out the `info` issue and state explicitly under which assumptions you answer.

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic I've opted to update the JSON in the question so that it is correct and fits the intent of the question.

Comment: @CommissarVasiliKarlovic `info` is the top level key. I havent stripped the json file.

Comment: @Ouroborus If you want to update the JSON, you can, but I haven't stripped it. Its just AS IT IS. I have edited ONLY `name` and `addr`

Comment: @John If that were the case, you would have gotten `JSONDecodeError` since the JSON as originally provided in the question is indeed invalid.

Comment: @Ouroborus Let me check I still have the original and the formatted one. Gimme 2 minutes.

Comment: @Ouroborus Yes. I posted the wrong one. My fault. I validated it online but seems, I have posted the wrong one. Apologies.